# Nicer way to convert string to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

Is there a nicer way to convert `NVARCHAR` to `INT` on SQL Server?

`SELECT CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(FLOAT, N'5.0'))`

Why do simple `CONVERT` or `CAST` cause errors?

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, N'5.0')
SELECT CAST(N'5.0 AS INT)
```

Comment: There is a decimal point in the string, therefore an int is not a valid conversion from a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do simple CONVERT or CAST cause errors?

Because the value you are trying to convert has a decimal point.  And integers don't have decimal points.

You can get around this using `DECIMAL` as well as floating point numbers:

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(10, 0), N'5.0')
```

`DECIMAL` accepts the decimal places (even more than 1) and rounds the value to the appropriate integer, so the result can be either larger or smaller than the input.

This has the same range as integer, so it is pretty equivalent -- and you can convert back:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, CONVERT(decimal(10, 0), N'5.0'))
```

Note that these are still subject to overflow errors, so I recommend `TRY_CONVERT()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `try_convert` and `isnull` functions together. `try_convert` will return null when it fails to convert. And `isnull` will use the fallback value if the first argument is null. But a good part of it it will use first arguments datatype so end result will be an int if use the below code :

```
declare @text nvarchar(20) = N'5.6'

select isnull(try_convert(int,@text),convert(float,@text))
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/80123/0)